# How i make my web application only available to smartphone user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

Hi i am developing a voting web application and i want voters to vote only from mobile and when they vist from computer to tell them that they can only vote from mobile is there is any way i can do that? I did not try any method because i could not found one. So please help

Answer (score -1):

Use a media query:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    display:flex;
  }
}
.block{
  display:none;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  This site is only available on mobile
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript to check the user agent, then use that to change the html.

```
if(
    navigator
    .userAgent
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes("mobi")
)
//Etc
```

You can also combine this with the `media` technique:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 613px) {
  #yolo {
    display:none
  }
}
```

somewhere in html:

```
<div id="yolo"></div>
```

Then back in the JavaScript, you can add an additional condition:

```
/*... Other part of if...*/
&& window.getComputedStyle?

(
    cs=>
    cs && cs
    .getPropertyValue("display") 
     == "none"
)
(
    getComputedStyle(yolo)
)
: true
/*Rest of it statement closing & other things...*/
```

Comment: User agent detection is not a recommended technique for modern web apps

Comment: @spectric says who? Then why does it exist?

Comment: User agent sniffing is a very noddy detection technique, user agent strings are a constant moving target, they should not be trusted alone.

Comment: @spectric says who? Why else does it exist, if not to be checked?

Comment: Just because something exists doesn't mean it's a good idea to use. Spectric's point is that if the user agent you are checking against has changed in a newer version of the browser you're targetting, your code no longer works. What's wrong with suggesting looking for a more consistent solution?

Comment: @alex the entire purpose of the user agent is to be checked by the developer to determine what kind of device etc is being used, there's nothing that will ever change regarding the word "mobile" in the agent, as this question said, however, checking the width is not at all reliable or consistent, it's possible someone with a desktop is using a smaller screen, or even a virtual machine etc., There's nothing in the standard methods of JavaScript that suggest checking the screen width for mobile or not, is a hack, but the standard, documented way to go about it, unlike the user agent

Comment: You seem to be right. I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent, although that suggests using `Mobi` instead of the full word `Mobile`. I've also seen using media query feature detection on `pointer: coarse`, but unsure how reliable that is

Comment: @alex changed it to mobi